# FFT analysis in LTSpice is giving wrong results during partial execution of time domain simulation (Details in body)

Tags: ltspice, simulation, fourier, fft, spectrum

In LTspice, while computing FFT using waveform window (View-> FFT), the results seems to be wrong  if FFT is computed after partial execution of simulation ( eg: if simulation is  paused in between)

-Although FFT simulation window considers only the partial duration.

**Why would the results be different if simulation data duration considered for FFT is same?**

***Wrong results (shown below):***

### [image]
[image]

***Correct result (shown below):***

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look wrong to me. Take a look to "spectral leakage":
https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2011/01/fft-and-spectral-leakage-2/

Comment: What if you change your `.tran` time in the 2nd example to `27.041411m`?

Comment: I think MFE is correct in this case you should stop the simulation at different pointscorrect in this case you should stop the simulation at different points until you reach the full sampling window, you should see the leakage reduce as the window gets bigger